# how to write regex expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have requirement to block certain user based on there chat word, below is the rules allowed and disallowed in regex

1. mob no should be banned
2. sexual context also banned
3. other than this everything allowed

in the expression/word i can give disallowed words like "rs|RS|rupee|1234567890" in the configuration and java regEx should give me output about whether that words is allowed or not.

Comment: `if(str.contains("rs|RS|rupee")){/*disallow*/}`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex pattern would be:

```
String configSting="Rs|RS|rs|rupee"; String
regEx="(?:^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z]))("+configSting+")(?:(?=[^a-zA-Z] )|)";
Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.regex.Pattern` class and `java.util.regex.Matcher` class  like below.

```
String str = "targetStr";
String regEx = "regEx";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
```